# Conflicting Google Maps API

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps, wordpress

My plugin is using the Google Maps API to auto-suggest locations when the user types in a few letters in an input field.

To do this, I enqueue the Google Maps API as follows:

```
wp_register_script( 'auto_location_map_library', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' . get_option('auto_location_maps_key') . '&sensor=false&libraries=places', array('jquery'), '1.0', false);
wp_enqueue_script( 'auto_location_map_library' );
```

Everything works fine and I do get the auto-suggestions. However, whenever it's tested on a theme that already included the Google Maps library, it breaks down entirely.

I've tried dequeue'ing the theme's library call in my plugin, but this didn't work and isn't a great solution.

Is there a kind of noConflict Google Maps call similar to that used in jQuery that I'm not aware of?

As a matter of interest, the code for referencing the autosuggestion is as follows:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    function initialize() {
        var autocompleteOptions = {
            <?php if (!(get_option('auto_location_countrycode') == '')) { ?>
                componentRestrictions: {country: '<?php echo get_option('auto_location_countrycode'); ?>'},
            <?php } ?>
        };

        if (jQuery('#search_location').length) {
            var input = document.getElementById('search_location');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, autocompleteOptions);
        }           
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
});
```

Comment: see what you found on firebug while you run google map ?

Comment: @Mahmood - In Chrome console, I get "Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

Comment: Remove the later one `google API` and try.

Comment: I can't cherry pick when to include the plugin gmaps call as I have no way of checking whether it was included in the theme - at least no way that I know how of...

Also, simply dequeue'ing the plugin gmaps call doesn't help as the more often that not, the theme gmap call doesn't include the places library I need.

Comment: You have to remove one instance `or` use `no conflict` after the first one.the google map library will be in `plguins->google-map folder`.

Comment: How does one do a noConflict on gmaps library call?

Comment: please check the source and put the files hierarchy here .So that we can guide you easily.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue you had with [my plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps/).

Try the following:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'randomfunction234_deregister_scripts',999);
add_action('wp_head', 'randomfunction234_deregister_scripts',999);
add_action('init', 'randomfunction234_deregister_scripts',999);
add_action('wp_footer', 'randomfunction234_deregister_scripts',999);
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'randomfunction234_deregister_scripts',999);

function randomfunction234_deregister_scripts() {


        $map_handle = '';
        global $wp_scripts;
        if (isset($wp_scripts->registered) && is_array($wp_scripts->registered)) {
            foreach ( $wp_scripts->registered as $script) {             
                if ( $script->handle !== 'YOUR_MAPS_API_ENQUEUE_HANDLE' ){
                    if ( strpos($script->src, 'maps.google.com/maps/api/js') !== false || strpos($script->src, 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api') !== false || strpos($script->src, 'maps.googleapis') !== false || strpos($script->src, 'maps.google') !== false) {
                        if (!isset($script->handle) || $script->handle == '') {
                            $script->handle = 'remove-this-map-call';
                        }
                        unset($script->src);
                        $map_handle = $script->handle;
                        if ($map_handle != '') {
                            $wp_scripts->remove( $map_handle );
                            $map_handle = '';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Make sure you change `YOUR_MAPS_API_ENQUEUE_HANDLE` to the name of your enqueue handle when you enqueue the Google Maps API, which in your case is `auto_location_map_library`.

What this script does it try deregister any enqueued scripts in the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `wp_head`, `init`, `wp_footer` and `wp_print_scripts` hooks.

Caveat: This will not deregister any scripts that have been hardcoded in by other plugins or themes - those will forever be a pain in our sides.